# Running out of Memory - bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: java, android, memory, imagebutton

I have searched a lot for a solution for my up and down buttons and can't seem to get anything working. When using the ImageButtons in the program, I am able to press three ImageButtons before I get OutOfMemoryError. Please any help will be great.

```
for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
{
    keys[i].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                for(int down = 0; down < keys.lenght; down++)
                {
                    if(v == keys[down])
                    {
                        keys[down].keys[down].setImageResource(drawIDDOWN[down]);
                        keys[down].setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    }
                }
             }
             if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
             {
                 for(int up = 0; up < keys.length; up++)
                 {
                     if(v == keys[up])
                     {
                         keys[up].setImageResource(drawIDUP[up]);
                         keys[up].setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                     }
                 }
             }
        return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size    exceeds VM budget
android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:498)
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:501)
android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:280)
f7kidzCalc.com.KidzCalcActivity$1.onTouch(KidzCalcActivity.java:253)
android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3881)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent
(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent
(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent
(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there an easy way to garbage collect, recycle images or just anything? I'm stuck..

Comment: what is the size of the image?

Comment: Around 60kb for each ImageButton

Comment: try to implement OnTouchListener methods in your main class instead of using an inline class instance. although I doubt that it will help.

Comment: I not sure if it would take care of the problem...

Comment: If you are just changing image, a selector xml file would be better, unless you have a reason not to use one

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction to an tutorial on selector xml?

Comment: UPDATE: I just tried my code on the device instead of the emulator and it works perfectly. I am going to keep pressing buttons and playing with the app to see if I get any errors....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not storing the activities or context in any other part of your program. This really messes with your memory management and causes lots of leaks.

You can send pointers to it using methods such as:

**Good Form**

```
public void doSomethingtoContext(Context c){
   c.getApplicationContext()....//Variable 'c' only lasts for the length of the method
}
```

**Bad Form**

```
public static Context cOnText;
public void doSomethingtoContext(Context c){
   cOnText = c; //DO NOT STORE THIS VALUE HERE
}
```

Basically, what I am trying to say is that, most of the times the image size aren't the problem, but instead something easy to overlook like this case.

Hope this helps.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the size of the image you are using.  I had the exact problem. Image i was using was >500kB. Reduced size is around 50-60kB.

Comment: All but one image is under or around 60kb.. I do have a background image that 320kb but I didn't think that a problem...

Comment: Howbig is the image in pixels?   That's what matters for this.

Comment: Each image is 300x300px. I wanted to make use of the button for an tablet later...In the xml, its at 80dip

Comment: @antlersoft: I have'nt reduced image dimensions, but problem dissapeard after reducing size. 

btw, my images are 200x200px

Comment: I use selector now...so much better!